# Application of merge sort

Tags: c, database, sorting

Merge sort application

Can anyone tell me what does online sorting means?I could not find perfect answer.
Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They can both be used any time you need to organize data in a defined order. I know that's a fairly broad answer, but it's the only reasonable way to answer a broad question.

Comment: Um.... anywhere you need to sort large data?

Comment: if you do not have a large(ish) amount of items to sort, use insertion sort.

Comment: @pmg If `qsort` is available there is no reason to ever use an O(n^2) sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Klas: You have no guarantee on what algorithm `qsort()` implements. See http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html. That implementation uses insertion sort for 4 or less items.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, not true. Sometimes O(n^2) can be faster than O(n log n) for small n. It all depends on the constant factors that are ignored in calculating big-O.

Comment: @Mark and pmg Sorry, I meant implement, not use. My point is that you have to have a really good reason for adding the complexity of coding a sorting algorithm instead of using one that is almost guaranteed to be bug free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quicksort gained widespread adoption, appearing, for example, in Unix as the default library sort function, whence it lent its name to the C standard library function qsort and in the reference implementation of Java.
>
> Merge sort type algorithms allowed large data sets to be sorted on early computers that had small random access memories by modern standards. Records were stored on magnetic tape and processed on banks of magnetic tape drives . merge sort is implemented with disk drives.

For more read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#References

Answer (score 0):

Their applications vary; it depends on the size and contents of what you're sorting.

Quicksort is one of the fastest sorting algorithms, so it is commonly used in commercial applications.

Merge sort is used mostly under size constraints because it isn't as hefty an algorithm as Quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

Both algorithms can be used in distributed systems for sorting data.
Merge sort is a typical example used in online sorting. 
On the other hand quick sort also has some usage in graphic/game development where u need to sort data points and cluster them out.